# Unit Test Chaincode with InvokeChaincode

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I have a function in one of my chaincode contracts that calls the Golang SDK's `stub.InvokeChaincode` function in order to call another chaincode and get it's response before continuing with the currently invoked function.

When I try to unit test this function using the mock stubs from the `github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim` package I get memory errors because of this call to invoke an external secondary chaincode function.

Is there a way to unit test functions that have this built in?

Comment: Please provide minimal, reproducible example code.